# Derivative with respect to a function under integral in calculus of variations (partial derivation)

Tags: integration, derivatives, calculus-of-variations

I am solving a variational calculus problem, in which the functional is in the form of:
$$
J[p(t),\lambda]=\int_a^b\left(t^2\cdot p^2(t)+t^2\int_0^t p^3(\tau)\cdot g(\tau)d\tau -{\lambda}\cdot{p(t)}\right)dt
$$
So the Lagrangian function in in the following form (Lagrangian itself includes an integral!!)
$$
  L = t^2\cdot p^2(t)+t^2\int_0^t p^3(\tau)\cdot g(\tau)d\tau -{\lambda}\cdot{p(t)}
$$
Now I'm confused, how can I use Euler-Lagrange equation for solving this problem. In other words how can I integrate $\int_0^t p^3(\tau)\cdot g(\tau)d\tau$ with respect to $p(t)$? I think a partial derivative method can be used, but I can't find the right answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe $$\frac{\partial \int_0^t p^3(\tau)\cdot g(\tau)d\tau}{\partial p}=\frac{\frac{\partial \int_0^t p^3(\tau)\cdot g(\tau)d\tau}{\partial t}}{\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}}$$

Comment: I've test it but it is incorrect, you can test it with an example for $p(t)$

Comment: You do realize that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{p}}=0$ and tested $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial p}=2t^2 p+t^2 p^3 g/\dot{p}-\lambda p$$ right??

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I put for example $p(\tau)=sin(\tau)$ and test the answer by your equality.

Comment: Is anything known about the signs of $a$ and $b$? Is $a<b$?

Comment: @ Qmechanic Thanks a lot, the Polfosol answer was right, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. The standard formula for [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) does not apply to double integrals. But luckily we can rewrite OP's functional $J[p]$ as a single integral with the help of [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem).
2. In this answer, we will assume that $0<a<b$, and leave it for the reader to work out other cases. In more details, OP's functional reads
   $$J[p]~:=~J_1[p]+J_2[p],$$
   $$ J_1[p]~:=~\int_0^b\! \mathrm{d}t~L_1,\qquad L_1~:=~\theta(t\!-\!a)  \left[ t^2 p(t )^2 -\lambda p(t )\right],$$ 
   $$J_2[p]~:=~ \int_a^b\! \mathrm{d}t_1  \int_0^{t_1}\! \mathrm{d}t_2 ~t_1^2~g(t_2)~p(t_2)^3 ~\stackrel{\text{Fubini's Thm}}{=}~\int_0^b\! \mathrm{d}t_2  \int_{\max(t_2,a)}^b\! \mathrm{d}t_1 ~t_1^2~g(t_2)~p(t_2)^3 $$
   $$~=~\int_0^b\! \mathrm{d}t~L_2, \qquad L_2~:=~\frac{1}{3}\left[b^3\!-\!\max(t,a)^3\right]g(t)~p(t)^3.$$
   Therefore OP's functional becomes a single integral
   $$J[p]~=~\int_0^b\! \mathrm{d}t~L,\qquad  L~:=~L_1+L_2.$$
   EL equation
   $$0~=~ \frac{\partial L}{\partial p(t)}~=~\theta(t\!-\!a) \left[ 2t^2 p(t )  -\lambda  \right]+\left[b^3\!-\!\max(t,a)^3\right]g(t)~p(t)^2$$
   becomes a quadratic equation in $p(t)$.